# Objective-C: Help - my xib won't show?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xib

I have the following Objective-C code:

```
MainMenu *main= [[MainMenu alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[[self navigationController]pushViewController:main animated:YES];
NSLog(@"hello");
```

I have a class called 'MainMenu' with a corresponding header file and xib file. No matter what I do, it simply won't show. I have confirmed that the code gets to the above, because of the NSLog('hello').

I've been pulling my hair out for hours now and I simply cannot get to the bottom of it.

I hope someone can help,

---

Edit - still having problems...

Here are some screenshots of my project setup:

[image: Project topology]

[image: MainMenu.xib]

[image: PrestoCab11ViewController.xib]

[image: MainMenu.xib]

---

Ok, so I tried this:

```
MainMenu *main= [[MainMenu alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[[self navigationController]pushViewController:main animated:YES];
[self.view addSubview:main.view];
```

But it still doesn't work...

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you tried setting the `initWithNibName` param? To something like (I assume) `@"MainMenu"`.

Comment: What causes the navigation controller to show up? A table-row selection? Button press? UIAlertView?

Comment: Your `MainWindow.xib` does not have a `UINavigationController`, only a `UIViewController`. Start a new problem that uses a `UINavigationController` to see how to set up your `MainWindow.xib` and `AppDelegate` properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that initWithNibName is nil should not be the problem because if it is given nil it looks for a nib with the exact name of the class.

Two things:

1) Make sure you have run a clean recently and make sure that file is correctly being loaded.

2) Make sure navigationController is not nil, if it is then you need to make sure you make a navigation controller if you are not intending on using a navigation controller, consider using:

```
- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController 
                          animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont pull your hair just look at your code closely: You have nil in your initWithNibName. Whats MainMenu is it a viewController or what ? and place your correct nib for your to get Hello.

**Updated as asked :**

```
MainMenu *main= (MainMenu *)[MainMenu alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:main];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
NSLog(@"hello");
```

Comment: MainMenu is a UIViewController. What should initWithNibName be?

Comment: @Eamorr: I have posted the correct answer above. Just check if you have MainMenu as the XIB file in your project.

Comment: This shouldn't be the issue because, according to the [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName:bundle:), if you specify `nil` for the nibName parameter you must provide a nib file in your bundle whose name (without the .nib extension) matches the name of your view controller class.

Comment: @Eamorr: Do you think you have XIB file in your project name MainMenu ?

Comment: Have you imported the file using #import "MainMenu.h" in the class ? Dont know why but just check.

Comment: @Eamorr: If its a button press try presentModalViewController instead of pushViewController.

Comment: Can you show me the code in which you use presentModalViewController ?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you setting the `nibName` to `nil`? If the name of the nib is `MainMenu`, then you want:

```
MainMenu *main= [[MainMenu alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenu" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:main animated:YES];
[main release];
```

Are you sure that you have a `UINavigationController` in order to push a new view?

Hope that Helps!

Comment: Tried initWithNibName:@"MainMenu", but it's still the same problem. Xib simply won't show

Comment: To be clear, it's perfectly fine to set the nibName to nil; the default behaviour is to look for a nib with a name matching the controller's class.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue is that you do not have a navigation controller set up .Try to present the view controller by

```
[self presentModalViewController:main animated:YES];
```

Comment: But I do have a navigation controller in my xib file! I really don't understand all this...

Comment: If navigation controller is set up make sure that the outlets are connected and ensure that it is not nil for the class in which you use the above statement.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the object owner is in fact MainMenu and the view is connected.

In the MainMenu NIB, select File's Owner and the click on the Identity Inspector. Class should match your VC class name.

Then select the main View in your NIB and click on the Connections Inspector. The view outlet should be connected to your File's Owner.

If those are both set correctly, then post some more surrounding code. Notable point, if those are both set,

```
MainMenu * main= [[MainMenu alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:main animated:YES];
```

will load the correct NIB and display it.

What *are* you seeing? Another point if MainMenu is a subclass of some other VC with a NIB you will have to change the base class' init to override the default behavior, for example:

```
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil == nil ? @"BaseViewController" : nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]
```

But in that case you would have to specific the NIB that will override the base view controller's.

Post more code and let us know what you are seeing when you run.